# PHP parsing specific date string

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

An `API` call is returning me a date as a string in the following format:

```
/Date(1358208000000)/
```

Now, I would like to parse this string into a date object (PHP).

I could use *str_replace* remove the ***/Date(*** and ***)/*** and divide the unix timestamp with 1000, but that seems a bit complicated for this matter to me.

Any thoughts on how I could parse this easily to a date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you want easy way. Yo can use like below;-

```
<?php
    $str = '/Date(1358208000000)/';
    $int = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // get the number only from the string
    echo date ('Y-m-d',($int/1000)); // convert number to seconds and get correct date
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/595171

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "/Date(1358208000000)/";
$ts = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $string), 10);
$date = date("m/d/y g:i a", $ts);
```

https://3v4l.org/0oHbh

there is nothing to divide, it's already a valid timestamp...

Comment: Shouldn't that timestamp (1358208000000) output 15-01-2013?

Comment: besides, dividing it is going to push the date back further as opposed to giving you a more recent date. the lower the timestamp the further it is in the past.

Comment: This timestamp is resulting in 11/25/45009, so it is probably defined in milliseconds, which means you should have to divide it with 1000 to get a valid one: 15-01-2013. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I do agree @Anant. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: lol i couldnt read your mind about the date you wanted..... other than the divide it's the exact same solution...'